# (sqlite3.OperationalError) cannot change into wal mode from within a transaction using Chatterbot

Tags: python, chatterbot

Running into this issue when trying to run Chatterbot on Python. The point in which the code fails is the last line of this code:

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer 
from chatterbot import ChatBot 
bot = ChatBot('Test') #Failing here
```

Here is the full error code:

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) cannot change into wal mode from within a transaction (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

I tried reading through the error reports on the GitHub in which ChatterBot is being hosted, and their solution was to downgrade ChatterBot to a previous software version but this did not fix the issue.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to hear that you weren't able to find the solution you were looking for. To help others help you, could you please include the version of ChatterBot that you currently have installed, s well as the SQL Alchemy version?

Comment: Hello Gunther. I actually ran this on another machine and it seems to be working. Turns out it was an issue with my Mac. Works perfectly on my PC. Thank you for the help nonetheless!